# Mac developing - building an application with toolbar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, toolbar

I am new to mac developing, and kind of confused. I am trying to create a program with a toolbar, but can't seem to get it working. Can anyone explain me the steps needed to do this? 
Beside, is there any control on the mac developing system similar to iPhones UITabBarController?
Thanks, Hans Espen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detailed article about creating toolbars in Cocoa:

[Creating Toolbars for Mac OS X](http://www.macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2002/03/15/cocoa.html?page=1)

I don't know of anything like the iPhone's tab bar for the Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Toolbars on the Mac are not similar to anything on the iPhone.

Read Apple's documentation on toolbars here:

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Toolbars.html

If you're still stuck after reading that, provide a more precise description of what you're having problems with.